# Not creating file (Java)

Tags: java, file, bufferedwriter

For some reason I keep on getting the following error when I compile my code. I have the correct preprocessor directives (import statements), and no syntax errors but whenever I compile my code I am given

Comment: There's no int in your txt file

Comment: You reached the end of your file it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

probably,your dateFile is empty which might be the reason for this exception

```
public int nextInt()
```

Scans the next token of the input as an int.
An invocation of this method of the form nextInt()

Returns:
the int scanned from the input

Throws:
**InputMismatchException** - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range

**NoSuchElementException** - if input is exhausted

**IllegalStateException** - if this scanner is closed

refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Reader
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException
  {

    File dateFile = new File("test.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(dateFile);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(dateFile);

    try
    {
      // if file doesnt exists, then create it
      if (!dateFile.exists())
      {
        dateFile.createNewFile();
        bw.write("1");
        bw.close();
        System.out.println("Done");
      }else
      {
        int duration;
        String ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the amount of problems per training session (with number in minutes):");

        while(!ans.matches("[0-9]+"))
        {
          ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please re-enter the amount of problems per training session (with number in minutes):" );
        }

        duration = Integer.parseInt(ans);
        System.out.println(duration);
        bw.write(""+duration);
        bw.flush();

        int numSessions = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Number of sessions is: " + numSessions);
        String fileName = ("sessionNumber"+numSessions);
        File newSession = new File(""+fileName+".txt");
        System.out.println(fileName);

        if (!newSession.exists())
        {
          newSession.createNewFile();
          System.out.println("IT DOES NOT EXIST!");
        }

        fw = new FileWriter(newSession.getAbsoluteFile());
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        bw.write(duration);
        bw.close();
      }
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Now it should work.
I add this two lines:

```
bw.write(""+duration);
bw.flush();
```

you were never write in the File.
Remember to .flush() your buffer.. if you want it to write on the file before you close it!
notice that i changed the path of the file to let it work on my pc so change it again